# How can I add a new column asynchronously to a mat-table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I can already define the columns using an array, but there is a column that I want to hide, but after a service runs, I want to then show it. I tried the following but the table didn't update:

```
columnsToShow.push("someColumn")
```

and I have the definition in my table:

```
<mat-table>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="someColumn">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>...</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">...</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

But the column never appears.

Comment: could you create a plunkr or stablitz ?

Comment: @Optiq sorry, I really don't know how to use stackblitz. I'm just trying to add a new column after a certain amount of time. Not when the page first loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mat-header-row` to update you header:

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

In Component class update `displayedColumns` as your needs:

```
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
```

[Code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vn5tqd)

From [official documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#3-define-the-row-templates):

> by changing your column list provided to the rows, you can easily
>   re-order and include/exclude columns dynamically.

Comment: I'm asking how would you add a new column asynchronously. Like how would you add another column 5 second later or after an http request?

Comment: @AskYous, What's wrong with my example? You mean, you want to add new column, not in the datasource? Or hide some column and after the `http` request show again?

Comment: I apologize. I understand your code now. I basically have to reassign the entire array.

Comment: @AskYous, no problem, anything can happen